# Cannot convert value of type Float to expected argument type NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, nsnumber

I am calling a method in objective c from swift class. My objective c method is expecting number in the format of NSNumber. I did not define the number type in swift but still I get the below message. Is there any way to resolve this?

[image]

```
- (void)getPercentageMatch:(NSString *)answer listOfAnswers:(NSArray *)validAnswers completionBlock:(void(^)(BOOL isSuccess, NSNumber *percent))completionBlock {
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setValue:answer forKey:@"myanswer"];
[params setValue:validAnswers forKey:@"answers"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [AuthorizationHandler createAuthReq:@"POST" path:@"validateAnswer" params:params];

AFJSONRequestOperation *op = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:req];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSDictionary *responseheaders = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
    if (completionBlock) {
        completionBlock(true, [responseheaders valueForKey:@"percentage"]);
    }
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (completionBlock) {
        completionBlock(false, 0);
    }
}];
[op start];
return;
}
```

I also forced completion block typecasting

```
as! completionBlock(Bool, NSNumber)
```

but this doesnt work.

I am new to swift and any tutorials/pointers will be appreciated :)

EDIT 1:

When I modify completion block

```
let completionBlock = { (isSuccess, percent) in
        print("-------", isSuccess, percent)
    }
    MTRestkitManager.instance().getPercentageMatch(_:text, listOfAnswers:validAnswers, completionBlock:completionBlock)
```

I don't get any error. However, if I add one slight modification again I get an error.

[image]

Why is the behavior changing?

EDIT 2:
Following kelin's solution, made the following changes

```
    @IBAction func submitButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    answerTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    if answerTextView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
        ZUtility.showError(NSLocalizedString("Please enter answer before submitting", comment: ""))
        return;
    }
    if answerTextView.text.isEmpty {
        ZUtility.showError(NSLocalizedString("Please enter answer before submitting", comment: ""))
        setPlaceholderText()
        return;
    }
    let text = answerTextView.text as String
    let completionBlock = { (isSuccess, percent:NSNumber) -> (Void) in
        self.handleAnswer(isSuccess: isSuccess, percent: Float(percent))
    }
    MTRestkitManager.instance().getPercentageMatch(_:text, listOfAnswers:validAnswers, completionBlock:completionBlock)
}
```

On the last line I am receiving an error : Cannot convert value of type '(Bool, NSNumber) -> (Void)' to expected argument type '((Bool, NSNumber?) -> (Void)!'

Comment: post your swift code not image..

Comment: How does that make a difference?

Comment: See this...  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1825618

Comment: Got the point. Thanks :) Let me modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, `Float` is inferred from the `handleAnsewer()` function of `self`. You should define proper type in your `completionBlock` manually:

```
let completionBlock = { (isSuccess, percent: NSNumber?) in
    self.handleAnsewer(isSuccess: isSuccess, percent: percent.floatValue ?? 0)
}
```

And remember, you can't automatically typecast in Swift, you should call explicit initializers, such as `NSNumber(value: myFloat)` or `Int(percent`).

P.S. I bet you come from python :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, kelin. I modified my code and it compiled but fails at run time with the message EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on line:
MTRestkitManager.instance().getPercentageMatch(_:text, listOfAnswers:validAnswers, completionBlock:completionBlock as! (Bool, NSNumber?) -> Void)

Comment: Seems like `Float(percent)` returns optional value. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I still face the issue given in EDIT 2. Any idea why expected argument type NSNumber is optional? I believe, in objective-c there is not concept like this.

Comment: I modified the completion block as (isSuccess, percent:NSNumber!) and it worked! Thanks for the hints. But I still wonder how it worked. I made the percent compulsory but objective-c is expecting optional.

Comment: The `getPercentageMatch` function wants `(Bool, NSNumber?)` not `(Bool, NSNumber)`. See the update.